# How to initialize nested dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7, initialization, nested

I'm using Python v2.7 dictionaries, nested one inside another like this:

```
def example(format_str, year, value):
  format_to_year_to_value_dict = {}
  # In the actual code there are many format_str and year values,
  # not just the one inserted here.
  if not format_str in format_to_year_to_value_dict:
    format_to_year_to_value_dict[format_str] = {}
  format_to_year_to_value_dict[format_str][year] = value
```

It seems a bit clumsy to initialize the first level dictionary with an empty dictionary before inserted into the second level dictionary.  Is there a way to set a value while at the same time creating a dictionary at the first level if there is not one already there?  I imagine something like this to avoid the conditional initializer:

```
def example(format_str, year, value):
  format_to_year_to_value_dict = {}
  add_dict_value(format_to_year_to_value_dict[format_str], year, value)
```

Also, what if the inner dict should itself initialize to a list?

```
def example(format_str, year, value):
  format_to_year_to_value_dict = {}
  # In the actual code there are many format_str and year values,
  # not just the one inserted here.
  if not format_str in format_to_year_to_value_dict:
    format_to_year_to_value_dict[format_str] = {}
  if not year in format_to_year_to_value_dict[format_str]:
    format_to_year_to_value_dict[format_str][year] = []
  format_to_year_to_value_dict[format_str][year].append(value)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

> If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with a value of default and return default.

```
format_to_year_to_value_dict.setdefault(format_str, {})[year] = value
```

Or [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
format_to_year_to_value_dict = defaultdict(dict)
...
format_to_year_to_value_dict[format_str][year] = value
```

---

With lists in the inner dict:

```
def example(format_str, year, value):
  format_to_year_to_value_dict = {}

  format_to_year_to_value_dict.setdefault(format_str, {}).setdefault(year, []).append(value)
```

or

```
def example(format_str, year, value):
  format_to_year_to_value_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

  format_to_year_to_value_dict[format_str][year].append(value)
```

---

For dicts of unknown depth, you can use this little trick:

```
tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)

my_tree = tree()
my_tree['a']['b']['c']['d']['e'] = 'whatever'
```

Comment: Is there anything like defaultdict for the lists in the inner dict case?

Comment: Was just editing that in. You just need a function that returns `defaultdict(list)` and not just `{}` for missing keys.

Comment: The `tree` solution is genious. For a slightly less hacky versersion that does exactly the same, consider `def tree(): return defaultdict(tree)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import defaultdict
format_to_year_to_value_dict = defaultdict(dict)
```

This will create a dictionary that calls `dict()` when you access keys that don't exist.