# How do I build a dictionary from child to parent?

Tags: python, sql, dictionary

So I'm working with python and sql. I have some data structured like this:

- Grandparent:

  - Parent

    - Child

The current code, when given the child gets a list containing the parent and the grandparent (it uses the parent ID to get the grandparent)

Now I need to get this info in a hierarchical way, so I thought of it as a  dictionary, but I can't find the way to add a new "superkey" that englobes the other keys in each iteration.

(Note: It can have more than 3 levels, but I can't know a priori how many levels of parenting there will be)

EDIT: This is the current code:

```
def Parenting(ChildID)  
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Parent_Child where ChildId ="+ChildID)
    Pathway_Du_ID = cursor.fetchall()
    Pathway_IDs = []
    done = []
    for Path in Pathway_Du_ID:
            Pathway_IDs.append(Path[0])
    for ele in Pathway_IDs:
            ele = str(ele)
            if ele not in done:
                    done.append(ele)
                    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Parent_Child where ChildId ="+ele)
                    Du = cursor.fetchall()
                    for l in Du:
                            Pathway_IDs.append(l[0])

    return Pathway_IDs
```

The final dict would look like a typical nested dict (maybe with more levels than in this example:
Grandparent { Parent1: [Child1, Child2], Parent2: Child3}

Comment: What is the parent id of grandparent?

Comment: I don't really get your question. So all IDs (parent, grandparent and child) look the same, that's why I build it "upside down" with the same iteration

Comment: My question is, how does the child know who is parent is. Also, give me your code

Comment: The child knows it from the SQL. Just added the code

Comment: Watch out for sql injection attack vulnerability in your code. Don't build your sql strings like that. The documentation teaches you to do it without vulnerabilities.

Comment: @iri my problem is that I can't know the grandparent ID a priori, so I need to build the nested dict on the go (and I don't know how to do that)

Comment: Could you give an example what your dict would look like?

Comment: Have a look here for nested dicts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819428/how-to-initialize-nested-dictionaries-in-python?rq=1

Comment: again, this works when building it "from outside to inside", but I want to do it the other way around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I might do it with sqlite. In `Parenting()` I establish a parallel data structure, indexed by ID, to hold individual relationships while the tree is being built.

```
import sqlite3
import pprint

def init_db(conn):
    with conn:
        conn.execute("""create table People (
                            Id integer primary key ASC,
                            Name)""")
        conn.execute("""insert into People values
                            ( 1, "Homer"),
                            ( 2, "Bart"),
                            ( 3, "Lisa"),
                            ( 4, "Maggie"),
                            ( 5, "Abe" )""")

        conn.execute("""create table Parent_Child (
                            ChildId INTEGER UNIQUE,
                            ParentId INTEGER )""")
        conn.execute("""insert into Parent_Child values
                            (1, 5),
                            (3, 1), (4, 1), (2, 1)""")

def Parenting(conn):
    global root
    population_by_id = {}
    sql =  "select ParentId, ChildId from Parent_Child"
    for parent_id, child_id in conn.execute(sql):
        parent = population_by_id.setdefault(parent_id, {})
        child = population_by_id.setdefault(child_id, {})
        parent[child_id] = child
    sql = """select ParentID from Parent_Child
              where ParentID not in (select ChildID from Parent_Child)"""
    eldest = next(conn.execute(sql))[0]
    root = { eldest : population_by_id[eldest] }


if __name__=="__main__":
    conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
    init_db(conn)
    Parenting(conn)
    pprint.pprint(root)
```